# Trying out a SQL to select some attributes of Students who are registered and not registered for a Module

Tags: mysql

Go to link to see the table
Table Link: https://www.scribd.com/document/357739284/DBDI-Relational-Schema-Data

What I am trying to do: 
Trying to display student Names, email, moduleID and their results who are registered for a module and also display students on the same list who are not registered for a moduleID

SQL I Try out but problems:

```
SELECT sName, email, Module.moduleID, Module.results
FROM Student, Module, Registration
WHERE Student.studentID = Registration.studentID AND ModuleID.moduleID = Registration.moduleID
UNION 
SELECT sName, email, Module.moduleID, Module.results
FROM student
LEFT JOIN Registration ON Student.studentID = Registration. StudentID
WHERE Registration.moduleID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a space between the dot (.) and StudentID in the last left join.  The space needs to be removed as shown below.  I also changed the upper query to ANSI standard syntax to be consistent with the bottom query.  In the upper query, the Module table was misnamed as ModuleID.  Join key between Student and Module was incorrect.  Corrected to StudentID.

```
SELECT sName, email, Module.moduleID, Registration.results
FROM Student    --<-- changed to ANSI Standard syntax
     INNER JOIN Registration on Student.studentID = Registration.studentID
     INNER JOIN Module on Registration.ModuleID = Module.ModuleID  --< Fixed Module table name
UNION 
SELECT sName, email, Registration.moduleID, Registration.results
FROM Student
     LEFT JOIN Registration ON Student.StudentID = Registration.StudentID  
WHERE Registration.ModuleID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Still getting a minor Error on SELECT line under UNION saying  invalid identifier

Comment: @Anthony You need to pay attention to where the columns are stored.  You're mixing your columns and tables which is causing the issues.